# Cross reference in Rust without Rc

Tags: rust

I want to have a list of items in a struct to reference other items from another list in the same struct. I can do this with Rc&RefCell but then code turns into a mess and I feel that employing Rcs for such a basic thing is an overkill.
So it looks like

```
struct A <'a> {
    items_b:Vec<B>,
    items_c:Vec<C<'a>>
}
...

struct C<'c> {
    item_b: &'c B
}
```

and the method to add an item

```
    fn add_c(&mut self, item_b_index:usize) {
        self.items_c.push(C::new(self.items_b.get(item_b_index).unwrap()))
    }
```

but it either fails with

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements

or, if I add lifetime to mut self, with

> cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time

so it becomes unusable. And I don't understand why lifetime matters here at all...

Full example in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9e435a409a765e5087d0c3cfa13a5b8).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What you are describing is a self-referential struct (with some disguise). There are many threads here about this, so this one here will probably get closed as duplicate by you-know-whom.

Comment: hmm, I thought it looks more lie a tree rather than a cycle to be  self-referential struct...

Comment: `self.items_c` contains reference to `self.items_b`, by construction, so `self` as a whole is indeed self-referential.